# Angular set timer for certain element

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

Here i have some jspdf function

```
  public captureScreen() {
    // Start from here 
    this.loading = true;

    const data = document.getElementById('convert');
      html2canvas(data).then(canvas => {
      const imgWidth = 208;
      const pageHeight = 295;
      const imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
      const heightLeft = imgHeight;
      const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      const pdf = new jspdf('p', 'mm', 'a4');
      const position = 0;
      pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
      pdf.save('Test.pdf');
      // Until here
      this.loading = false;
    });
  }
```

I want to make this function run for a second before it turns back the `this.loading` into false again. How can I make a timer that can set about 2-3 second before it executes the last code?

Answer (score 0):

Use set timeout function to make delay for few seconds

```
// When calling function
this.loading = true;
setTimeout(function() { captureScreen(); }, 3000);

public captureScreen() {
    const data = document.getElementById('convert');
      html2canvas(data).then(canvas => {
      const imgWidth = 208;
      const pageHeight = 295;
      const imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
      const heightLeft = imgHeight;
      const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      const pdf = new jspdf('p', 'mm', 'a4');
      const position = 0;
      pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
      pdf.save('Test.pdf');
      // Until here
      this.loading = false;
    });
}
```

Comment: you mean like this right ?   public timer() {
    setTimeout(function() { this.captureScreen(); }, 3000);
  }

Comment: yes and also set loading to true before setTimeout function to start loading and after executing the function inside capture screen then the loading will false

Comment: so i need to call the timer in my button right? i already did it but its said this.captureScreen is not a function

Comment: setTimeout(()=> {  this.loading = true; this.captureScreen(); }, 3000); instead of writing function use lambda function then it will work